# Red horizontal lines in my Aer LCD only in black colours

Tags: display, lcd

I am facing problem with my Acer v203HV. I see so many red lines – only in the black colours of my screen.

Like when I watch movies, whenever there appears something dark, there are red lines all over. I have Windows 7. In its transition effects like shutting down etc. I also see red lines.

Does anybody know what the reason for these red lines is?

Comment: Are you using the [native resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_resolution) of the LCD screen? I've seen the horizontal red line thing on several LCD displays only when using lower-than-native resolutions, not sure what exactly causes them.